# ServiceStack passing values in service to response attribute

Tags: c#, servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I have a service:

```
[SomeResponse]
public class SomeService : ServiceBase {
    public string[] CacheMemory{ get; set; }
    //....
}

public class SomeResposeAttribute : ResponseFilterAttribute {
    public override void Execute(IHttpRequest req, IHttpResponse res, object requestDto) {
            //I want to access SomeService->CacheMemory here?? How?
        }
}
```

Now, if I need to do something to `CacheMemory` in response attribute before I send it back. How do I get access to it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Filter Attributes don't have access to the Service instance, you'd use the `IRequest.Items` dictionary in to pass objects to different handlers throughout [ServiceStack's Request Pipeline](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations), e.g:

```
[MyResponseFilter]
public class SomeService : Service 
{
    public string[] CacheMemory { get; set; }

    public object Any(Request request)
    {
        base.Request.Items["CacheMemory"] = CacheMemory;
        //...
        return response;
    }
}


public class MyResponseFilterAttribute : ResponseFilterAttribute 
{
    public override void Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, object dto) 
    {
        var cacheMemory = (string[])req.Items["CacheMemory"];
    }
}
```